# Executing Privileged Instructions

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, operating-system, system

I have Intel i5 Processor and Windows 7 operating system. I was dabbling around with the system trying to learn more about it. I realized that I do not have access to privileged instructions of the processor. For example I cannot write to Model Specific Registers and code like the following fails to execute

```
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.code
main proc

    xor eax,eax
    xor edx,edx
    mov ecx,176h
    wrmsr

main endp
end main
```

Is there a way to write applications that can make complete use of the processor and the system with all its instructions without having to write Windows device drivers?

*P.S : I don't mind a system crash or file system corruption*

Comment: Inside a virtual machine...without any Operating System above you.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to play with this stuff inside a virtual machine.  If you do get a privileged instruction to run somehow, either from a device driver or some other context that executes in ring 0, you're probably going to lock up the system or worse.  (Worse = corrupts your filesystem on disk).

If you want your code to run in long mode, rather than 16bit real mode, maybe start with an open-source toy OS, and put your code in right after it initializes stuff and switches out of real mode.  memtest86+ is one example of a bootable program, and I think it's open source.

You'll probably want to use a bootloader like GRUB, too, to get your non-Windows toy OS loaded.

You'll probably want to look at [the OSdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/) for tutorials and guides to stuff that is normally only done by OSes, whether you consider your running-on-the-bare-metal program for playing with stuff an OS or not.

Of course, once you get something working in an emulator like bochs (which has a built-in debugger that would let you single-step whatever code you want), you might want to test it on real hardware.  If grub in a VM can load it, so can grub on your real hard drive.  Or syslinux on a USB flash drive would mean you didn't have to mess with your Windows install's bootloader.

Answer (score -3):

I assume you know what is privilege instruction and that it can only be executed in ring 0 the most privilege level of sofrware. and second assumption is that you want to play with operating system not necessarily windows which is not as good as open source OS for learning OS with code available

you have some options to try with:

write linux module and transition to privilege level and perform privilege operation there.

implement your own system call for specific purpose.

use emulators bochs, qemu simic etc to test your code with some extra effort.

Comment: I use both Windows and Linux but frankly each time someone said "_this_ is better than _that_" I can't help and I have to ask..."Why? In which sense? To do what? In which context?". BTW he tagged his question with [tag:Windows] and he said he'd avoid to write kernel stuff...I wouldn't suggest him to write a **Linux** kernel module...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti GNU/Linux is better in a lot of ways than Windows.  For the purposes of *my own* personal use, I would say it *is* better.  However, I completely agree with you that putting it that way with no qualifiers is silly, and that this isn't a useful answer.

Comment: i am much sure that linux is much better in understanding operating system primitives due to availability of code and most of books for OS are written for unix kernel. as for answering question is concerned, i am much sure that asking person starting his journey on OS otherwise he should not have ask this question so I try to answer to guide him in every possible way. You two down voted then plz guide the asking person as well in better way especially by using windows

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree, that's why we use *nix (in some circumstances and in a specific scenario _this_ is _better_ than _that_). I can't resist to rant each time I see such _broad_ assertions...

Comment: @shami: right idea with suggesting an open source project in a VM or emulator as a starting point, but wrong open source OS.  If you just want to play around with x86 privileged instructions, Linux is WAY more complex than you need.  It's also going to be harder to find your way around, because Linux is portable to *many* different architectures, not just x86.  I'd remove my downvote if you edit your answer to put a qualifier on "not as good".  e.g. "An open source OS would be easier to modify for playing around with privileged instructions.  Linux has example modules for ..."

Comment: @shami In OP example the only privileged instruction is `wrmsr`. For sure it's used **also** in OS kernel but it's **also** useful in virtualization (not so common we deal with that stuff) and debugging (especially useful for I/O). Whatever is the reason...that's not what OP is asking for. OP knows what he is doing, he wanted to know if (by case) it's possible to use p.i. in ring 3. Is it easier because you have source code? Hmmm take a look to Linux kernel source code. Anyway for a toy k.m. or d.d. you won't don't really need to _make your hands dirty_ with too many kernel stuff...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thats why(unknown purpose of privilege instr.) I try to provide all possible ways to transition to ring 3 which are known to me. Regarding code, i am in favor of always look on code for understanding of OS with out that How can you understand OS. In my humble capacity, I never saw good books on windows internal with availability of code.

Comment: @shami yes because Windows code isn't open source but there is a nice open source project to _rewrite_ an open source Windows _compatible_ OS: **ReactOS**. It's a pretty good project!